# Android getExternalFilesDir throws SecurityException "not owner"

Tags: android, testing, android-sdcard

I have a program which has worked on android for some time.  It has a test project which passes on most devices.  However, now I'm trying to run it on an nvidia tegra, which is a more up to date version of Android (4.4.2), and I'm hitting a problem.  When I call "getExternalFilesDir(null)" it throws a security exception.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Package blah.blah.test does not belong to 10088
```

Trying to track it down, I find that on most devices "ls -l" in /mnt/sdcard/android/data looks like this:

```
drwxrwxr-x system   sdcard_rw          2014-07-03 13:02 blah.blah
drwxrwxr-x system   sdcard_rw          2014-05-19 13:07 blah.blah.test
```

But on the tegra it looks like this:

```
drwxrwx--- u0_a88   sdcard_r          2014-07-04 09:58 blah.blah
drwxrwx--- u0_a85   sdcard_r          2014-07-04 09:59 blah.blah.test
```

So I'm guessing the fact that the test project has a different userID when installed on a tegra is the cause of the problem, due to the changes to external drive access in the latest android versions, and I'm wondering how I'm supposed to write test code now? Is there a magic trick I'm missing?

**edit1:**
The test project looks like a completely separate project in eclipse, to me.  It contains many classes derived from AndroidTestCase, and I run it by right clicking and selecting "debug as android junit test".

The main program can definitely access the sdcard when running normally.

Comment: And what is that program? Can you show that??

Comment: Can you provide more details regarding the test project? Is this a JUnit instrumentation test project? Or is this some totally independent project?

Comment: it seems that tegra has not givin permissions to write (sdcard_r). Maybe it is on users side because of the "App-Ops"

Comment: does my edit above answer the test project question?  I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are asking?

Comment: JUnit tests should run in the same process as the app itself, and so therefore should share a user ID.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Are you telling me that I am choosing to run them in a different process somehow, because I accidentally ticked a box somewhere?  Do you know where?